# Conditional formatting of a table in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to visualize a cohort analysis, and wanted to use `RenderDataTable` in shiny to get this sort of a visualization where I would be able to highlight all the cells based on a separate column having values 1/0, with 1 being shaded and 0 not being shaded.

[image: Cohort Table]

I Tried a couple of things, including trying to use `geom_tile` in `ggplot2`, but it was of no avail. I also tried looking at `rpivotTable`, but I wasn't able to figure out how to shade certain cells.

Example Data:

```
df <- "
cohort  wk  value   flag
1   1   24  0
1   2   12  0
1   3   10  0
1   4   5   0
1   5   2   0
2   1   75  0
2   2   43  1
2   3   11  0
2   4   14  0
3   1   97  0
3   2   35  0
3   3   12  1
4   1   9   0
4   2   4   0
5   1   5   0"

df <- read.table(text = df, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you provide an minimum [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Your example image doesn't have a 0/1 column and it has cells shaded, not rows. Does it really represent your expected output?

Comment: Thanks @Molx, made the edits based on your comments

Comment: @Karthikg the best is to use DT (using the datatables JS library).  It allows to use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 8):

With the `DT-package`:

# global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
    thead(
       tr(
         th(rowspan = 2, ''),
         th(rowspan = 2, 'Cohort'),
         th(colspan = 10, 'Wk')
       ),
       tr(lapply(paste(c('', 'f'), rep(1:5, each=2), sep=''), th))
    )
))
```

# ui.R

```
shinyUI( fluidPage( DT::dataTableOutput(outputId="table") ) )
```

# server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        df$flag <- as.factor(df$flag)
        x <-  reshape(df, timevar = 'wk', sep = '_', direction = 'wide',idvar ='cohort')
        row.names(x) <- NULL
        colnames(x)[-1] <- paste(c('', 'f'), rep(1:5, each = 2), sep = '')
        datatable(x, rownames = T, container = sketch,
          options = list(dom = 'C<"clear">rti', pageLength = -1,
                         columnDefs = list(list(visible = F, targets = c(3,5,7,9,11))))
    )%>%
       formatStyle('1', 'f1', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('white','lightblue'))) %>%
       formatStyle('2', 'f2', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('white','lightblue'))) %>%
       formatStyle('3', 'f3', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('white','lightblue'))) %>%
       formatStyle('4', 'f4', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('white','lightblue'))) %>%
       formatStyle('5', 'f5', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('white','lightblue'))) 
    })  
})
```

\

[image]

Comment: No disrespect to this answer that some user seem to have enjoyed, and got abounty too, but some additional explanations or comments would be nice, I've been staring at this for the last 5 to 10 min and I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Hi, it's been a while but I'm pretty sure I didn't explain much because everything I used from `DT` is well explained at its [website](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/). But if you have any particular doubts I can try answering them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction, I have indeed meanwhile found what I needed on this website! Well worth checking as much more telling that the help files of the package!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to color a DataTable you could do it like this:

```
require(plyr)

# Create matrix
m.val <- max(unlist(lapply(unique(df$cohort),function(ch){ length(which(df$cohort==ch)) })))
cohort.df <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df$cohort),function(ch){ 
  v <- df$value[which(df$cohort==ch)]
  c(v,rep(NA,m.val-length(v))) 
  }))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ('colorTbl',function (message) {
          console.log(message.row);
          var row = parseInt(message.row); var col = parseInt(message.col);
          $('#tbl').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(col).css('background',message.color);
        });
           ")
    )
  ),
  dataTableOutput("tbl")
)

color <- "#6CAEC4"
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  colorTbl <- function(){
    # Get rows we want to color
    sel.d <- df[df$flag==1,]
    for(i in 1:nrow(sel.d)){
      row <- as.numeric(sel.d[i,sel.d$cohort]) -1
      col <- as.numeric(sel.d[i,sel.d$wk]) - 1
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'colorTbl', message = list(row=row,col=col,color=color))
    }
  }

  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    # Wait until table is rendered, then color
    reactiveTimer(200,{colorTbl()})
    as.data.frame(cohort.df)
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui,server))
```

Here I use jQuery to color the rows based on your criterion.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in creating the plot with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = wk, y = cohort, fill = factor(flag))) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), color = "white") +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: Cohort Plot]

Rendering the plot in shiny should be trivial and since you have not provided any shiny code (e.g. server or ui), it's difficult to say where you could be experiencing a problem.