# Mixed types in Shiny datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

So I have a Shiny App that is basically a dataframe passed to the datatable function and formatted in a specific way (see picture below).

I want to put a string where there are 99999999999% values and blank cells while I keep the rest of the cells as numeric (I need the rest of the cells to be of numeric type so as to apply a color scale formatting on them). However, because of the very nature of dataframes, it is not possible to have different types in the same columns.

[image]

The question is: Do you know a way to have strings and numeric types in the same column of a data frame? Should I make some other workaround? In this case: Any idea?

Comment: Hope this background shades are for testing, they are eye killer. Regarding your question, convert dataframe all columns to formatted character.

Comment: @zx8754 Yep, they are obviously for testing. The problem of converting the columns to character is that I won't be able to apply color scales conditional to the values.

Comment: You can do as @zx8754 suggested and use hidden columns (with the original numeric values) to determine the colors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888834/conditional-formatting-of-a-table-in-rshiny/33509303#33509303

Comment: Just as an FYI, this http://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html is the official documentation. The feature is not yet available on the CRAN version.

Comment: You can use a list column.